# Hibernate using two oracle database, Error: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, oracle11g

I have two separate oracle schema that I pool information from and update. somehow when I have two hibernate.dialect pointing to the same dialect, it give me simultaneously fetch multiple bags error. If I change one of back to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, error disappear and compile but the table did not generate. 
Another question for hibernate. while my dataSource is MYSQL, I am able to generate all of the table I need, but when I switch my dataSource to oracle, it only generate three table.

Below is my persistent.xml

```
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.byuh.checklist.domain" />


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            autoReconnect=true
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.default_schema=checkList               
            hibernate.flushmode=NEVER

        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="oraSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="oradataSource">
    <!-- <property name="annotatedClasses"> <list> <value>edu.byuh.checklist.oraDomain.PSUserDetails</value> 
        <value>edu.byuh.checklist.oraDomain.HousingAssignment</value> <value>edu.byuh.checklist.oraDomain.HousingFee</value> 
        </list> </property> -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.byuh.checklist.oraDomain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            <!-- hibernate.show_sql=true -->
            hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
            autoReconnect=true
            hibernate.default_schema=SYSADM



            <!-- maxConnectionAge = 4 * 60 * 60 maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = 30 
                * 60 -->
            hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_size=${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.min_size=${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}
            hibernate.c3p0.timeout=${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}
            hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}
            hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}
        </value>
    </property>

</bean>
<!-- <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"> org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory 
    </beans:prop> -->


<!-- <beans:property name="hibernateProperties"> <beans:props> <beans:prop 
    key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</beans:prop> 
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop> <beans:prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"> 
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory </beans:prop> prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop 
    <beans:prop key="hibernate.default_schema">SYSADM</beans:prop> </beans:props> 
    </beans:property> </beans:bean> -->

<!-- Read in DAOs from the hibernate package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="edu.byuh.checklist.dao.hibernate" />

<!-- Transaction Config -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean id="oraTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
    p:sessionFactory-ref="oraSessionFactory" />
<!-- <aop:config proxy-target-class="true"/> -->


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

below is some of my domain class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "CheckListItem")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="itemType", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class CheckListItem implements DomainObject, Comparable<CheckListItem>{


//@SequenceGenerator(name = "MySequence", sequenceName = "my_seq", allocationSize=1)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "hibernate_sequence", sequenceName = "ChecklistItem", allocationSize=1)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Integer id;
private String title;
private String subTitle;
private boolean published;
@Column(length=2560)
private String contentTxt;
//list of student attributes
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<StudentAttribute> appliesTo;
```

another domain class

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "Fk_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class InfoItemUser extends CheckListItemUser implements DomainObject {

private Integer tries;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is well explained in this great blog http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html it perfectly explains with a query example, why you can't have multiple bags, and proposes the solution

You have two eagerly fetched collections that hibernate due to mapping combination interprets as bag. One is visible from the code you posted in question

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<StudentAttribute> appliesTo;
```

You have three possible solutions:

- Have your collections lazily loaded
- Move the type from the List to Set if your business logic allows it
- Annotate your collections with @IndexColumn